# C++ linked list declaration

Tags: c++, new-operator

I come across a code as follow:

```
int* list = new int[5];
```

I never saw such declaration.  What does it do?  I suppose list is a pointer to an int?  Using VS debug environment, I can see list having one int value.  So how are the other element accessed?  Thanks.

Comment: It simply dynamically allocates a buffer with 5 `int` and assign it's address to the pointer named `list`. This is not what a linked list is. Basically this is how you `malloc()` in C++.

Comment: So how do I access each of these 5 elements?  What is style of this declaration called?

Comment: It is called a "mistake". Replace it with `std::vector<int> list(5);`, and get rid of the (hopefully) matching `delete [] list;`.

Comment: @CaTx You just access like an array, `list[0]` through `list[4]`.

Comment: Thanks Havenard.  @Jerry Coffin, the assignment forces me to do it that way.  It comes from the professor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Answer (score 1):

The statement is called <s>badly-mannered</s> **dynamic (memory) allocation**, involving two operators, `new` (`new[]`) and `delete` (`delete[]`). The `new` operator allocates memory and the `delete` operator deallocates memory.

Since it's a chunk of memory assigned to a pointer, it behaves mostly the same as an array (`int list[5]`), so you should access it as usually as you do with a pointer. Like

```
int *list = new int[5];
list[0] = 10; list[3] = 25; // Whatever
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    list[i] = 1+1;
```

You can see a list of topics about dynamic allocation in C++ on Stack Overflow [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+c%2B%2B+allocate+memory+new).

Comment: This style comes from the assignment.  Not sure if the professor deserves the comment.

Comment: @CaTx the assignment is a symptom of a common problem: Students graduate thinking they have learned to write C++ code and have actually been taught C programming. So while it's good to see they are teaching `new` and not `malloc`, it's not much of an improvement. Now knowing how to manually control your memory at a low level is an important skill, but the way it is being taught hypes up it's importance in day-to-day programming and the smarter alternatives, along with important concepts that do not exist in C, are put off or outright ignored.

Comment: Side note: If you are going to be messing with dynamic allocation, do yourself a favour and familiarize yourself with the [Rules of Three and Five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Then take a look at the Rule of Zero and think about how much easier it makes your job.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a linked list, but a construct known as dynamic memory. If you want to create an array normally, you would write something like

```
int myArray[3] = {
    1, 2, 3
};
```

Notice that when I write the size of `myArray` (3), I use a constant expression; If I were to write

```
int x = 3;
int myArray[x] = {
    1, 2, 3
};
```

It wouldn’t work, because `x` is a variable, not a constant expression. Note that even if `x` is a `const`, this still wouldn’t work. This is because before the program is run, memory needs to be allocated for the arrays.

When you say `int * myData = new int[3]`, you can create memory on the fly, without constant expressions. In this case, it would be perfectly fine to do this

```
int x = 3;
int * myData = new int[x];
```

However, `myData` is a pointer, not an array, so the common `sizeof(x) / sizeof(*x)` trick doesn’t work here.

Make sure that after your dynamic memory is no longer of use, you write `delete[] myData`. This de-allocates the memory block and allows other memory to be stored in its place.

This memory is a block of memory just like an array. A linked list, however, is totally different, and would take a while to explain. Check out the [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) on it.

Comment: @iBug what do you mean?

Comment: C++ allows `const int a = 3; int x[a];` and then `x` is of type `int[3]`.